# google.visualization.Map seems not to work with only one address on data. Is it a bug?

Tags: google-maps

google.visualization.Map seems to work only with multiple addresses on data. When I only have one address, the map was greyed out, and if I drag the map, it shows up. It works fine when I have multiple addresses on the data.

Here is the sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {
        "packages":["map"],
        // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
        // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
        "mapsApiKey": "AIzaSyDJCykPxyz" //I have real key. 
    });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Lat', 'Long', 'Name'],
          [37.6153, -122.3900, 'Airport'],
          [37.4422, -123.1731, 'Shopping']
        ]);

        /*var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: {lat:31.4422, lng:  -122.1731}
        }*/
        var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));
        map.draw(data, {
          showTooltip: true,
          showInfoWindow: true
        });
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map_div" style="width: 600px; height: 450px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I comment out the middle line of data [37.6153, -122.3900, 'Airport'], Map does not show up. Otherwise it works. Is it a bug? is there a workaround for it? My project requirement is to dynamically display a map for an address selected by users.

I tried to change zoom level, but it does not fix the problem.

Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Input an address and dynamically load a google map -- It should be a common use case. Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I know it works for the use case if I use iframe with embedded map Key. However, our application requires further map actions like displaying other locations such as merchants near the place. We need to use javascript key for our application.

Comment: The point: (37.4422, -123.1731) is in the pacific ocean off the coast of California.  If you only have one point, it goes to the closest zoom, which (apparently) does not have tiles there.  Pick a point somewhere on land (preferably a populated place (like someplace "shopping" might make sense), it should work.

Comment: It still looks like a bug to me. I put 30.4285339,-97.7565683 (one point) which is an Austin Address. It greyed out, and after I drag the map and it shows up. But when I put two points, map shows up correctly.

Comment: Does look that way (like it is a bug).  With those coordinates I get no tiles, on a refresh I get one tile (but surrounded by grey).  However, bugs should be reported in the bug tracker, not here.

Comment: I'm working on a work around. Add a left location and another right location, and then remove the two markers. How can I find the markers on Geo Chart map? map.markers seems not to work.

Comment: You don't have access to the internals on a Geo Chart map (maybe use the Google Maps Javascript API v3).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I do need to report the bug and let google fix it. I'm new to google chart map, what's the URL for reporting a bug?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes#reporting-bugs